# Prove or disprove "The set of points at which a sequence of real valued measurable functions converges to a point of [0,1] is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know the following is true:

The set of points at which a sequence of real valued measurable functions converges (in R) is a measurable set. (This is proved by the definition of "Cauchy"="convergence")

However, I have no clue at all if this is true "The set of points at which a sequence of real valued measurable functions converges to a point of [0,1] is measurable."

If [0,1] were a countable set, then the statement would be correct. But it is uncountable, so I guess the statement is wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1]$?

Comment: If converging in R, "the sequence converges" is equivalent to "the sequence is Cauchy." In [0,1], it may not be the case, since it is a subset of R.

Comment: Be specific, the sequence of real valued measurable functions are from any measurable set W to R.

Comment: Please refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165171/set-of-convergence-is-measurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the set $C=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid (f_n(x))_n\ \text{converges}\}$ is measurable. Try to intersect $C$ with
$$
\bigcap_{i\geqslant1}\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}\{x\in\mathbb R\mid -1/i\leqslant f_k(x)\leqslant1+1/i\}.
$$