# Clarification on set notation for set of points where a given sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that, given a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_{n}\}$, the set of points at which $\{f_{n}\}$ converge is measurable.

My solution is to first define $f(x) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$, which is measurable. Then we also know all the differences $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)|$ are measurable, as well.

Now, I want to represent the set of points where these functions converge, but I am not entirely sure. I've reduced it to two possibilities, but am not sure which one is correct:

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x : |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{k}\}$$

or

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x : |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{k}\}$$

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is exactly role of $m$ in second formula? It only appears as an index of the union, but $m$ itself is nowhere to be found inside the expression $\{x: |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{k}\}$.

Comment: By the way, see t.b.'s answer [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/145724/49227) :)

Answer (score 2):

We are looking to find the $x$ such that $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence, i.e.:

$$\{x \mid \forall \epsilon >0 :\exists n: \forall m \ge n: |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \epsilon\}$$

Translating the quantifiers to unions and intersections one by one, we obtain:

\begin{align*}
& \{x \mid \forall \epsilon >0 :\exists n: \forall m \ge n: |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \epsilon\}\\
=& \bigcap_{k \ge 1} \left\{x \mid \exists n: \forall m \ge n: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \frac 1k\right\} \\
=& \bigcap_{k\ge 1} \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \left\{x \mid \forall m \ge n: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \frac1k\right\} \\
=& \bigcap_{k \ge 1} \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{m \ge n} \left\{x \mid |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \frac1k\right\}
\end{align*}

In the formulation with the $\limsup$, this corresponds to your second option once you let the innermost intersection start at $n = m$.

To see that the first option is incorrect, consider any sequence which happens to satisfy $f_1 = f$.